# What's the use of main returning IO Something rather than IO()?

Tags: haskell, io, program-entry-point

I'm reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/ ... And something surprised me:

> Because of that, `main` always has a type signature of `main :: IO something`, where `something` is some concrete type.

? So `main` doesn't have to be of type `IO()`, but rather can be `IO(String)` or `IO(Int)`? But what's the use of this?

I did some playing...

```
m@m-X555LJ:~$ cat wtf.hs
main :: IO Int
main = fmap (read :: String -> Int) getLine
m@m-X555LJ:~$ runhaskell wtf.hs
1
m@m-X555LJ:~$ echo $?
0
m@m-X555LJ:~$
```

Hmm. So my first hypothesis is disproven. I thought this was a way for a Haskell program to return exit status to the shell, much like a C program starts from `int main()` and reports the exit status with `return 0` or `return 1`.

But nope: the above program consumes the `1` from input and then does nothing, and in particular doesn't seem to return this `1` to the shell.

One more test:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~$ cat wtf.hs
main = getContents
m@m-X555LJ:~$ runhaskell wtf.hs
m@m-X555LJ:~$
```

Wow. This time I tried returning `IO String`. For reasons unknown to me, this time Haskell doesn't *even* wait for input, as it did when I was returning `IO Int`. The program seems to simply do nothing.

This hints that the value is really not returned anywhere: apparently, since the results of `getContents` are nowhere used, the whole instruction was skipped due to laziness. But if this was the case, why was returning `IO Int` not skipped? Well yes: I did `fmap read` on the `IO` action; but same stuff seems to apply, computing the `read` is only necessary if the result of the action is used, which - as the `main = getContents` example seems to hint - is not used, so laziness should also skip the `read` and hence also the `getLine`, right? Well, wrong - but I'm confused why.

What's the use of returning `IO Something` from `main` rather than only `IO ()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually multiple questions, but in order:

1. The 'result' of `main` doesn't have a meaning, that is why it *can* be `()` or anything else. It's not used at all.
2. The reason types other than `IO ()` are allowed for main is for convenience; Otherwise you'd always have to do something like `main = void $ realMain` to discard results (you may well want to have an action that could return a result which you don't care about as the last thing that happens) which is a bit tedious. IMHO silently discarding things is bad and so I'd prefer if `main` was forced to be `:: IO ()`, but you can always get that effect by just supplying the type signature yourself so it's not really a problem in practice.
3. Side point: If you want to exit with a specific exit code, use [`System.Exit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Exit.html)
4. The reason `fmap read getLine` consumes output and `getContents` doesn't is because `getContents` is lazy and `getLine` isn't - i.e. `getLine` does read a line of text where you'd think it does, whereas `getContents` only does any actual IO if the result is "needed" in the Haskell world; Since the result of `IO` isn't used for anything that means it doesn't do anything if `getContents` is your whole `main`.

Comment: I think it's kind of nice that I can write `main :: IO a` or (equivalently) `main :: IO Void` to indicate explicitly that `main` does *not* terminate by falling off the end but rather performs an explicit exit, dies by exception, or runs indefinitely. It doesn't really matter in practice, but it feels right.